# Is it possible to use vmm/vmd for non-CLI VMs? [OpenBSD]

Tags: virtual-machine, openbsd

**Question**: Can vmm/vmd/vmctl be used for non-text virtual machines?

I have been considering setting up OpenBSD as a dedicated operating system to run virtual machines. However, it appears that these possibly cannot handle graphics. 


**TL**;**DR**: Basically, I could not find any documentation on if vmm/vmd can run graphics. 

My question is can it or can it not? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no graphics, just the serial console.
But of course you may still install X apps and do X forwarding - e.g. "ssh -Y vm iridium &"

Comment: [Signal Desktop on OpenBSD via vmm(4)](https://icyphox.sh/blog/signal-vmm/) (via ssh)